# Listen for Oracle Database changes in .net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

I have a windows service application written in .net 3.5 that needs to know when data is added or modified into an Oracle Database.

Currently the service does some awkward bit of polling that is both slow and buggy.

Comment: Any data added to any table in any schema?  Why?  What are you trying to accomplish that cannot be done with existing facilities in oracle itself?

Comment: I need to listen for insert/update events in a specific table. The windows service business logic is complex, it communicates with external services to further process the newly inserted/modified data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for - **Using Database Change Notification With ODP.NET and Oracle Database 11g**

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/changenotification/odpnetchg_otn.htm

Comment: This should work nicely. In Oracle 11g it appears to be called Continuous Query Notification (CQN): http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/changenotification/index.html