# How can I await that a table is empty / message queue processed?

Tags: c#, oracle, asynchronous

I have a table that acts as a message queue. A message is processed if `search_flag is Null`. Currently, I am running the below method in order to check if the Table Is empty (in this case a view of this table). If it is Empty I would want to keep processing the data.

```
public async static void CheckMessageQueue(int waitTime = 1)
{
    var count = 1;
    var loop = 0;
    using var oracleConnection = GetOracleConnection();
    while (count > 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(waitTime * 1500);
        const string sqlSelect = "select count(*) from v_mq";

        var dr = await GetDataRead(sqlSelect, oracleConnection);

        while (dr.Read())
            count = int.Parse(dr.GetValue(0).ToString() ?? string.Empty);

        loop++;
        if (loop > 50)
            break;
    }
}
```

And the `GetDataRead` method.

```
static async Task<OracleDataReader> GetDataRead(string sqlQuery, OracleConnection oracleConnection)
{
    var cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, oracleConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
    var dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    return (OracleDataReader)dr;
}
```

The above code works, though the issue I have here is I am `Sleeping` and waiting for a static time, I would want to move to the next task once it has processed all straight away.

So I would want to have something as `await CheckMessageQueue()`.

If I use the above approach without sleep, wouldn't this make it a heavy burden on the system?

One Idea would be to constantly query the database, as per below. Though I am afraid it could cause any performance issues instabilities.

```
public async static void CheckMessageQueue(int waitTime = 1)
{
    var count = 1;
    var loop = 0;
    using var oracleConnection = GetOracleConnection();
    while (count > 0)
    {           
        const string sqlSelect = "select count(*) from v_mq";
        var dr = await GetDataRead(sqlSelect, oracleConnection);
        while (dr.Read())
            count = int.Parse(dr.GetValue(0).ToString() ?? string.Empty);      
    }
}
```

Can someone suggest the best way how to deal with it?

**UPDATE:**
I can't have an event to listen to for a table unless I can await till the event is fulfilled.

Though is there a possibility to create a trigger/constraint in the PL_SQL, which would the C# connection force to await till the specified process is fulfilled?

On C# side:

await TableIsCleared ();

//Keep doing Tasks only After TableIsCLeared the search_flag is marked as Null.

On Oracle (PL_SQL side)

Somehow notify C# code that the async task has been completed, executing till all finished.

Comment: How is the table emptied? Is it processed concurrently by another thread or process?

Comment: Yes, it is being emptied by multiple services Multi Thread Wrapper (with 15 processes)

Comment: How about this? [Listen for Oracle Database changes in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700319/listen-for-oracle-database-changes-in-net)

Comment: This part would focus on listening to the Oracle DB and then triggering an action. If I listen in the middle of my code lines, the event might be triggered later. Though It gave me an idea, though not sure if this is something we can do. Please see the Edited version for it.

Comment: It is possible to convert any event to an async method, using a `TaskCompletionSource`. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340162/how-to-await-an-event-click/58342849#58342849). In case you use .NET 5, a non-generic [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource) class has been introduced, so there is no need for a throw-away type like in the example.

Comment: True, though I would not know how to specify the completion task, e.g. It would trigger on each time the row has been updated, but I would only want it to be triggered once all of the rows have been updated. This complicates things I believe....

Comment: I don't know much about Oracle, but I expect that it should be possible to request notifications for a precise event, like when a specific SQL query would return at least one record, or a specific value. But I may be wrong. If this is not possible, you could consider doing it manually using triggers. You could add a `DELETE` trigger to the `v_mq` table, and make sure that when the last row is deleted, a row is added to another table, named for example `Push_Notifications`, and attach the notification mechanism to that table.

Comment: Gosh! This would be perfect! I just need to figure out how to actually do this!

Comment: I hope you really need this, because it sounds complicated to implement, to configure, to deploy and to maintain, and will probably increase the SPOFs (single points of failure) of your app!

Comment: It is for testing purposes, not the app itself. to understand how to save time till the last second.

Comment: Another idea, based on your original pulling approach, would be to adjust the pulling rate/tempo based on the existing number of records. Pull slowly while there are lots of records, speed up when the records are few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I will go with the flow as per last comment:

```
public static void CheckMessageQueue(int waitTime = 1)
{
    var count = 1;
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    using var oracleConnection = GetOracleConnection();
    while (count > 0 && DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Minutes < 2)
    {
        if (count > 50)
        {
           Thread.Sleep(count * 100);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }

        const string sqlSelect = "select count(*) from msg_queue where search_flag='Y'";
        var dr = GetDataRead(sqlSelect, oracleConnection);

        while (dr.Read())
            count = int.Parse(dr.GetValue(0).ToString() ?? string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of 'Thread.Sleep()' use 'await Task.Delay()', which is not blocking.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not involve waiting at all.